# Laravel 5.8 Macros in TestCase Setup function

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

As I get more into testing in laravel 5+ but specifically in 5.8, I tend to want to write my own assertions to deal with tedious actions. My current methodology is to store a bunch of macros in my Base Testcase file in the setup function.

Not completely relevant, but I reference my own testcase file which I pull in from a composer package and it follows from project to project as I refine it.

However it's getting to the point where there are a fair amount of macro's and I'm beginning to feel pain when searching for something a macro that needs to be updated or writing another one new one near it. So I feel like a refactor is in order, but I'm not sure what the best way to refactor this would be.

Is there a way if cleverly using traits or service providers, or even a pipeline class that could accomplish the same thing?

Here is an example of my TestCase File

```
<?php

namespace Quicktools\Tests; // Not Relevant but just being pulled in

use \Exception;
use Quicktools\Model; // Same, the laravel base model except macroable
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection as BaseCollection;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use \Tests\CreatesApplication;


    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        //TESTRESPONSE ASSERTIONS

        //MACROS HERE (with an example for clarity)

        TestResponse::macro('data', function ($key = null) {
            if (!is_null($key)) {
                return $this->original->getData()[$key];
            }
            return is_null($this->original->getData()) 
                   ? null : collect($this->original->getData());

        });



        //COLLECTION ASSERTIONS

        //MACROS HERE



        //VUE COMPONENT ASSERTIONS

        //MACROS HERE


        //STATUS ASSERTIONS

        //MACROS HERE


        //AJAX/AXIOS ASSERTIONS

        //MACROS HERE



    }
}
```

Is there a way to break these macro's into different files so it's more easily organized?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this by idea while developing another package, where I was registering a macro, and realized that you can register you macros in any package. So to organize this you might make yourself a simple testing or assertions package. In a package you can register more than one service provider and set the up to autoload.

I haven't tested the idea but ordering may become important for loading purposes. Say for example your data macro is being used in another macro. It may break based on ordering if your data macro is not yet registered.

But once thats all hooked up, you may be able to simply add a `Testing/TestResponseSeviceProvider` and `Testing/CollectionSeviceProvider` etc... so you have organized test segments.

Another thing you may want to consider is splitting them into different packages. For example I have a set of turbolinks assertions, which I only ever use when I'm writing a turbo links laravel app. So I split that into it's own package so I'm not adding dead-weight to a project that has no need of it.

I hope that helps someone. If you need a full example, leave me a comment and I'll post one.